# Enabling SSL for Oracle Business Intelligence components using Fusion middleware control (EM)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic-10.x, obiee

I am writing a script which will automate the OBIEE configuration to enable SSL.

In one of the step in EM (Fusion middleware control page ) i need to expand Business Intelligence Folder -> coreapplication -> in the security tab go to secure sockets layer tab and enable SSL and give the SSL certificate location.

The above steps are done through the UI and i want to automate these. Any ways of doing these through a python script ?

Thanks

Comment: @Victor HDC any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done that, but it may be possible using some of these [WLST commands for SSL configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13813/custom_infra_security.htm#CHDEHHJF):

> The following command imports a certificate from file cert.txt into wallet1, for Oracle Internet Directory instance oid1, in application server instance inst1:

`wls:/mydomain/serverConfig> importWalletObject('inst1', 'oid1', 'oid','wallet1', 
'password', 'Certificate','/tmp/cert.txt')`

There is also a topic on [SSL automation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e10105/ssl_scripting.htm#ASADM11574) in the Administrator guide.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Almost definitely, you should be doing this through WLST. Anything written based on the EM interface is liable to break any time Oracle decide to modify it, which could be anytime. WLST is the recognised API for making configuration changes.

However, if you would like the loaded shotgun ... then go and check out CasperJS, which is a Javascript-based headless web browser and will let you interface with a web page programatically to your heart's content. If you really want to use python, the requests library is very good.